# CASE Statement for Order By Clause with Multiple Columns

Tags: oracle

I want the Order by statement to change the column sort order according to the condition.

For example, if you have columns A, B, C, D and the condition value is entered as a parameter (pType)

- if pType = 1 Sort A, B, C, D
- if pType = 2 Sort B, C, D, A
- if pType =    3 C, A, B, D

Order by Case When Statement is applied and used as follows.
An error has occurred.

```
Order by
Case
when pType = 1 then A, B, C, D
when pType = 2 then B, C, D, A
when pType = 3 then C, A, B, D
```

How should I use it?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function [`DECODE()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/DECODE.html#GUID-39341D91-3442-4730-BD34-D3CF5D4701CE):

```
ORDER BY DECODE(pType, 1, A, 2, B, 3, C),
         DECODE(pType, 1, B, 2, C, 3, A),
         DECODE(pType, 1, C, 2, D, 3, B),
         DECODE(pType, 1, D, 2, A, 3, D)
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this works.

```
with t1_ as
(
  select 1 as ptype, 10 as a, 5  as b, 20 as c from dual union all
  select 1 as ptype, 6  as a, 10 as b, 21 as c from dual union all
  
  select 2 as ptype, 20 as a, 2 as b, 16 as c from dual union all
  select 2 as ptype, 100 as a, 1 as b, 90 as c from dual
)

select 
* 
from t1_
order by
case when ptype = 1 then a end asc,
case when ptype = 1 then b end asc,
case when ptype = 1 then c end asc,

case when ptype = 2 then b end asc,
case when ptype = 2 then c end asc,
case when ptype = 2 then a end asc
```

fiddle url for reference https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d567ebdd94c3febe83598a2d6c0b4dc0